# Retrieve data from specific table format

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm having some trouble in Excel.. wondering if someone could enlight me?

Suppose you have an excel with two sheets , sheetA and sheetB

on sheetA you have a table such as this

```
item 1
a                         value
b                         value
c                         value
d                         value
item 2
a                         value
b                         value
c                         value
d                         value
item 3
a                         value
b                         value
c                         value
d                         value
```

.... and so on

Also we can't assume any fixed positions, as sometimes we might have an item without any of the subitems, or with more than others, for example:

```
item X
a                        value
c                        value
d                        value
item Y
a                        value
b                        value
c                        value
d                        value
e                        value
item Z
c                        value
d                        value
e                        value
f                        value
```

And on sheetB I would like to retrieve specific subitems values such as this

item 3

b                         (I would like to use a function to look for and find item 3 in this case, and return the value of b

What should be the most efficient way to do this? Could you help me?

---

For example

On sheetA we have

Item1
a        700
b        500
c        800
Item2
a       750
b       550
d       320   (we don't have "c" in item2, but "d" instead)
Item3
b       1020 (we don't have "a" in item3)
c       740
d       120
e       470   (additional "e" in item3)

Now on the same workbook but in a different sheet, I would like to have a formula that would return the value of b, for example, of different items, 1,2,3, as below:

Item2, b = the function would return 550
Item3, b = the function would return 1020
Item1, b = the function would return 500

Could this be done in excel?
Regards

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That data format is horrible, and would be so much better if it was split into three columns (item, sub_item, value). It almost looks like you're showing a Pivot view of a 3-column data pull. Is there any way to have your data populated in 3 columns? How are these data populated?

Comment: Hi, it comes from a export from another software into excel, and its huge (thosands of lines)- meaning changing its format would take ages :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, lets say the items in Sheet1 column A is unique. You would then run VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP("b", Sheet1!$A:$B, 2, FALSE)
```

Which would look for the first exact match in the first column of range Sheet1!$A:$B and then return the corresponding value in column 2 of the range. VLOOKUP's advanced and newer sibling is XLOOKUP, which gives a bit more freedom (the search column doesn't have to be column 1, you can search from the bottom up etc). You can also break VLOOKUP up into two steps:

```
=MATCH("b", Sheet1!$A:$A, 0)
```

Which returns the row number as index where the first match occurred, and then:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B, MATCH("b", Sheet1!$A:$A, 0))
```

Which returns the value at the matching row number in column B.

The reason for this explanation is quite simple. A normal VLOOKUP won't do. We need to do two MATCH searches. First we need to find the row number for say "item 3", then run a second MATCH using the first as a *starting point*. So the row index to the first occurrence of "item 3" is

```
=MATCH("Item 3", Sheet1!$A:$A, 0)
```

The range to search for "b" is then

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A, MATCH("Item 3", Sheet1!$A:$A, 0)+1):INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A, MATCH("Item 3", Sheet1!$A:$A, 0)+10)
```

Assuming a maximum of say 10 sub-items (you can make the +10 as big as you want).

Now lets MATCH search for the correct "b" in the above range, which will return the *row index offset* (relative to *starting position* calculated above):

```
=MATCH("b", INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A, MATCH("Item 3", Sheet1!$A:$A, 0)+1):INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A, MATCH("Item 3", Sheet1!$A:$A, 0)+10), 0)
```

And finally INDEX into column B, using *starting position* + *row index offset*:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B, MATCH("Item 3", Sheet1!$A:$A, 0) + MATCH("b", INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A, MATCH("Item 3", Sheet1!$A:$A, 0)+1):INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A, MATCH("Item 3", Sheet1!$A:$A, 0)+10), 0))
```

**Ps. Excel 365 version using LET variables:**

```
=LET(item, "Item 3", subitem, "b", maxsubitems, 10, itemrow, MATCH(item, Sheet1!$A:$A, 0), itemrange, INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A, itemrow+1):INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A, itemrow+maxsubitems), rowoffset, MATCH(subitem, itemrange, 0), INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B, itemrow + rowoffset))
```

Comment: The double MATCH approach seems exactly what I need. I will try it and come back with the result! Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer with an EXCEL 365 version, which is computationally the same but more readable using LET variables as interim steps.

Comment: This works as wonders: =INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B, MATCH("Item 3", Sheet1!$A:$A, 0) + MATCH("b", INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A, MATCH("Item 3", Sheet1!$A:$A, 0)+1):INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A, MATCH("Item 3", Sheet1!$A:$A, 0)+10), 0))

This was not easy at all... Many thanks!

Comment: Couldn't try the =LET option, though. Not running excel 365, so that formula is not even available :(

Comment: As you can see the non-LET option calculates the same item *starting position* at least 3 times, which can be very inefficient for a large spreadsheet. With LET it is only calculated once and stored in a temporary variable. As an alternative you could split your formula across two cells. Calculate `=MATCH("Item 3", Sheet1!$A:$A, 0)` first, then reference that answer in the second cell. My dad would call this the poor-man's-LET ;)